# Декодирование json на Python

Tags: python, парсер, utf-8, decode, json-encode

Получаю данные от api в формате Json. Записываю их в файл, затем открываю файл на чтение и начинаю работать с данными. Проблема при парсере строки user_id не знаю как получить данные на русском языке. Вот код моего запроса:

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone



headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer токен',
           'Accept-Language': 'ru'}
now_date = datetime.now().isoformat()
end_date = "2034-12-31T00:00:00.000"


try:
    def get_info():
        s = requests.Session()
        response = s.get(
        'https://b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/orders/tanker?' + f"since_datetime={now_date}&since_datetime={end_date}",
        headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        print(data)



    with open('my.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
    with open('my.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
```

Получаю в ответе:

```
{'last_closed_at': '2023-01-31T10:18:20.169000', 'orders'[{'closed_at': '2023-01-31T13:18:20.169000+03:00','created_at': '2023-01-31T13:17:18.984000+03:00','final_price': '1489.2','fuel_type': 'a95_premium','liters_filled':'30.0','station_location'[52.238352,52.790106],'user_id':'89543ef5c3784889ab10129ef1257768'}]}
```

Этот же ответ и выводится в консоль при чтении файла. Что мне нужно сделать чтобы получить данные в консоли либо записать их в файл на русском языке. Код пишу в pyCharm на windows 7

Comment: Что тут должно быть на русском языке???

Comment: Строка user_id должна содержать ФИО

Comment: Нужно описание `API` читать. У вас есть ссылка на него, смотрели, что там написано про запрос, который вы делаете?

Comment: Имя поля `user_id` (если разработчики интерфейса не идиоты) намекает, что тут будет какая-то цифирь, ГУИД, а не ФИО.  ФИO, вероятно, получается отдельным запросом по `user_id`.

Comment: Ссылка на api https://taxi__business-api.docs-viewer.yandex.ru/ru/concepts/api20/tanker-info 
Значит я неправильно поняла попробую сделать отдельный запрос по user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Информацию о сотруднике по его `user_id` нужно получать [отдельным запросом](https://taxi__business-api.docs-viewer.yandex.ru/ru/concepts/api20/user-info), насколько я понял.

> GET [https://b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/users?user_id={идентификатор](https://b2b-api.go.yandex.ru/integration/2.0/users?user_id=%7B%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) сотрудника}

Comment: Спасибо большое)